# How to solve ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gives me ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT *
FROM   post 
       LEFT JOIN post_plus 
              ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.postid FROM post_category c1 JOIN post_category c2 ON c1.postid = c2.postid WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 ) AND c2.categoryid = 73 ) 
       where approve = 1 
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
          date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7;
```

what i've tried

```
    SELECT a.*
    (FROM   post 
...
    LIMIT  0, 7)a;
```

Comment: the subquery in the second `LEFT JOIN` does not have an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived table needs an alias and you were missing a join condition onto it as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM   post
       LEFT JOIN post_plus
         ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id )
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.postid
                  FROM   post_category c1
                         JOIN post_category c2
                           ON c1.postid = c2.postid
                  WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
                         AND c2.categoryid = 73) post_category /*<-- Missing Alias*/
         ON ( post_category.postid = post.id ) /*<-- Missing Join Condition*/
WHERE  approve = 1
ORDER  BY fixed DESC,
          date DESC     
LIMIT  0, 7;
```

Comment: It's working but instead of selecting posts from a specific category it prints all posts. ignoring the `SELECT DISTINCT...
                  WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
                         AND c2.categoryid = 73`

Comment: @user2696962 - You need `inner join` not `left join` then.